# flutter - no json is sent in the body of my http post

Tags: android, http, flask, flutter, http-headers

this is the code.

```
      Future<http.Response> postRequest () async {
        var url ='http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/message';

        Map data = {
          'message': '12345678901234567890'
        };
        //encode Map to JSON
        var body = json.encode(data);

        var response = await http.post(url,
            headers: { "accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json" },
            body: body
        );
        print("${response.statusCode}");
        print("${response.body}");
        return response;
      }

      postRequest();
```

//  also tried this: headers: {"content-type":"application/json" },

In my python flask server, the post message is logging, but with empty body into it.

The flutter app is running on Android Virtual Device and the server is still running on http://0:0:0:0:3000/ and it's using request.get_json() in the method.

Using postman, everything works as expected on my server so I see the problem in the app.

postman details:

POST: http://localhost:3000/api/message

headers
KEY | VALUE
Content-Type | application/json

Body raw

{
    "message": "opa"
}

also raised here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39351

Comment: are you using android emulator ?

Comment: hi @MohamedElrashid, yes!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try passing :
Future<http.Response> postRequest () async {
        var url ='http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/message';

       Map<String, String> data = { "message": "opa" };

        var body = json.encode(data);

        var response = await http.post(url,
            headers: { "accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json" },
            body: body
        );
        print(response.statusCode);
        print(response.body);
        return response;
      }

      postRequest().then((response){

     print(response.body);
});
```

Comment: Hi Shagun, thanks, but String data = { "message":"opa"}; is not possible. Map<String,String> can't be assgined to a variable of type 'String'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry . My mistake, I have edited my code. Please take a look .

Answer (score 0):

not sure if my finding is precious or not for community, but it seems that the URL was the problem. Everything works now, but I added a / in the end of the string in my flask app.

In Postman, I didn't have to do this. So if you have same problem, take care :)

The log from Flask server:

127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2019 17:41:32] "POST /api/message/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
opa
My Flask url is:

@app.route('/api/message/', methods=['POST'])
def function():

Comment: in my flutter app I added /  in the end of url *